# Firebase cloud function + iOS app : return true/false to client app from callable cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that update the user input when it is called from the client app. I want the function to return true/false for further action in client app. For example, if cloud function return true, new screen toggles. else, display alert. But the question is, how can I modify my code to return a true/ false from cloud function and read it in iOS app? Can Someone Help?

**this is my cloud function code (how to return true if success from here):**

```
exports.updateUserDetails = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  console.log("UID: " + uid);

  const phoneNo = data.phoneNo;
  console.log("Recieved: "+ phoneNo);

  const docRef = db.collection("Users").doc(uid);
  const code = docRef.set({
    "phoneNo": numberID,
    "dateUpdated": timeStamp,
  }, {merge: true});
  console.log("Phone Number updated");

  return {
    message: phoneNo,
  };
});
```

**this is the code from iOS App (how to read result for further action);**

```
func updateUser(){
    let data = ["phoneNo":"0125949022"]
    
    functions.httpsCallable("updateUserDetails").call(data) { (result, error) in
        print("Function returned")
        if let err = error {print(err)}
        if let res = result {print(res)}
    }
}
```

Comment: so, basically what you want is to return a `true/false` instead of the `phoneNo`? This does not make sense with your current logic, please elaborate on what are the conditions for this boolean return. From the way I am seeing it you should consider creating a separate function for that, as I believe you will have a different logic for this function.

Comment: I want to return if its successfully updated, the return `{success: true}` to the client app

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a `then()` that will wait for the async Firestore action to be completed, so applying it to your code you can do this:

```
const docRef = db.collection("Users").doc(uid);
docRef.set({
    "phoneNo": numberID,
    "dateUpdated": timeStamp,
}, {merge: true})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Phone Number updated");
    return {success: true};
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    return {success: false};
});
```

Comment: Hi from the client app how can I read the success results?